# Server Requirements for a 2000 visitor Event

Tags: vps, digital-ocean

I'm hosting a site for a "virtual event" and I want to make I have enough resources on the server. Please can someone confirm the rough requirements for the below:

- Up to 2000 visitors during a 2-day event – mostly watching an 'event' page which will load two iframes – a Vimeo video stream and a polling iframe
- a very small marketing site running on PHP (no other fancy tech) – only using some basic PHP includes and PHP variables to set some classes

I currently have:

- An VPS on Digital Ocean with 1GB of memory, with an SSD hard drive
- Running NGINX
- OPCache turned on
- The server is located in the same city as the virtual event that's being promoted, so in terms of server location this should be good

Are these specs enough? Should I upgrade the server (e.g. 2GB memory)? Do I need something like a load balancer?

Comment: I should mention I've tested the server on https://loader.io/ for 1 minute with 2000 responses (on a "clients per test" basis i.e. distributed) and received a 80ms response time, so that small test was fine

Comment: This is great—thank you